# How to get the predictions of a multi text classifier model using a csv file as test data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, bert-language-model

I have created a multi class text classification model using TF and Bert by following this blog post: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-text-classification-using-bert-and-tensorflow-d2e88d8f488d

For the model I used a test a dataset with 2 columns; sentence and sentiment (neg, neu, pos)
[image]

After I trained the model I saved it.

```
model.save('keras_model/sentiment_model')
```

Then I opened a new notebook and I uploaded the model:

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r'keras_model/sentiment_model', compile = False)
```

Despite the warning the model seems to be working. For testing I created 2 sentences in a list.

```
tweet_sentences=['De overheid wil windmolens in de Noorzee plaatsen', 'De demonstranten zijn tegen kerncentrales']
```

And tested the model:

```
def predict_class(reviews):
return [np.argmax(pred) for pred in loaded_model.predict(tweet_sentence)]

predict_class(tweet_sentence)
```

So basically the model works. But instead of using a list of strings for testing I like to use a csv with 2 columns: id and sentences.
[image]

Output should look like:
[image]

How can I do that??

Comment: You can load your csv in a pandas dataframe. Then, strip the 'sentences' column which will output you a series. This series can act as an input to your model. You should then get the same result. You can even do an active connection which when refreshed , the pipeline will automatically get the updated data and the model will result accordingly.